# React Router Redux - Prompt before hard transition to another domain

Tags: reactjs, routes, redux, react-router, react-redux

Want to trigger an alert or console log before the user navigates to a new domain.  From the docs, `setRouteLeaveHook` or `onLeave` should work.  I followed these [directions](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md).

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'


const Page = withRouter(
  React.createClass({

    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, this.routerWillLeave)
    },

    routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {
      console.log("Moved to different domain");
      return 'Your work is not saved! Are you sure you want to leave?'
    },

    render() {
      return <a href="http://google.com">Redirect</a>
    }
  })
)

export default Page
```

Page is the top level component in my app.  Using react-router v3 with redux.

How can I trigger an alert before the user leaves our site?

Comment: Update: sorry, just noticed you stated the version. Are you definitely using react-router v3? The latest version is 4.0.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but what is the problem? The hook is not being executed?

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca yes, the hook is not being executed

Comment: @Toby yes the project is v3.  upgrade will occur soon.  don't know that the version makes a difference here as long as >2.4 though

Comment: I think maybe you need to wrap your export with `withRouter` like this: `export default withRouter(Page)` maybe? **Update:** Added as an answer, I believe this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `withRouter` HOC wrapper on your export like this:

```
export default withRouter(Page);
```